# cordova config.xml android permissions

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

I am attempting to run the Android version of my PhoneGap (Cordova) app, and it's not listing the proper permissions.

When I install the app, it says it needs permission to record audio, access the file-system, network connections, etc.  It does *not* say anything about the Camera or the Internet -- both of which I need.

How do I set those permissions in the config.xml file?

I have googled the heck out of this, and I see a bunch of people talking about editing the Android-Manifest.xml file -- but that file is ALWAYS overwritten as soon as I type "phonegap build android".  So whatever modifications I make, they need to be in the Config.xml file!

I have also found numerous references to things that look like:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera />
```

But I was under the impression that those `<feature>` tags were deprecated back in PhoneGap 2.0?  At any rate, I tried them, and they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions should be set when you install a plugin : camera permission with the camera plugin...

And when you build the android app, the permissions are added to the androidmanifest.xml file.

I think the network permission are part of the "by default" permissions, so it's quite strange you don't have it...

I would suggest you remove all plugins and the android platform, then re-add the plugins and re-create the android platform. (the easiest is to manually delete the platforms/android and plugins folders in your app)

It may help you